# How to upload private/public key pair to Google App Engine - Standard environment without uploading them to GitHub?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am generating and verifying JWT token using private/public key pair(algorithm: RS256) in my node-express backend

I am using cloudbuild.yaml(Trigger) to deploy my app to Google App Engine - Standard environment. I want to deploy private/public key pair to Google App Engine(gcloud app deploy) with rest of the code base but I don't want to upload them to GitHub or add them to app.yaml as an environment variable.

What is the best approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The best way of accomplish this will be by using [Cloud KMS](https://cloud.google.com/kms/) 
this is the bets way to manage encryption keys on GCP.

There are a a few tutorial on how to acomplish this [here](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/accessing-the-api#google_app_engine) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/using-other-products). Also found [this tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/securing-managing-secrets-using-google-cloud-kms-3fe08c69f499/) which seems like it could help you with what you are looking to accomplish

Comment: Those are some very useful resources. I'll wait for some other answers before I mark this as an accepted answer. Thank you